# How cloud storage provider like google store and distinguish data of different users?

Tags: storage, cloud

My question is simple. How the cloud storage provider like google store data of different users on same server.
For example there are two user storing there data on a single drive on cloud. My question is how back-end system distinguish between these different user data saved on same hard drive, so that there is proper isolation between the data of these two users.

Comment: You're starting from a point with so many wrong assumptions that it's truly impossible to get anywhere useful with this, I'm afraid. For a start, don't assume that just because you have an account with Google Drive or Microsoft's OneDrive that somewhere in one of their datacentres is a drive with your name (or even your name and the names of other people) on it.

Comment: I understand your point, that why i am asking how 2 users save their data on the single drive.

Comment: @RishabhSoni This site is for professional sysadmins, we make this SUPER clear when you sign up, you're not one as you clearly don't understand the very basics of this - imagine going onto a site for professional airline pilots and asking "How metal bird keep in sky????" - well that's what you've done here, learn the basics.

Answer (score 1):

Google's implementation is proprietary but whatever method they use, they simply give the user access to their own files, just like any other existing system.

There isn't even a need for enhanced permission control on the server since all user operations are controlled through their own API which deals with authentication and privacy issues.